# How to fix Error during SELECT operation: Error: Too many connections

Tags: mysql, node.js

Good afternoon, I use promises to connect to a database. I constantly see the error:

```
Error during SELECT operation: Error: Too many connections
    at PromisePool.query (/root/node_modules/mysql2/promise.js:341:22)
    at /root/akaciBot/mysqlmain.js:23:45
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 'ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR',
  errno: 1040,
  sql: undefined,
  sqlState: '',
  sqlMessage: 'Too many connections'
}
```

How to fx correctly? The database indicates the maximum connection: 151. As I understand correctly, I reset the connection after executing the code.

My code:

```
return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
        const pool = mysql.createPool({
            host: " ",
            user: " ",
            port: "3306",
            database: " ",
            password: " ",
            waitForConnections: true,
            connectionLimit: 10,
            queueLimit: 0
        });
        let connection;
        try {
            connection = await pool.promise();
            const [rows] = await connection.query(connect);
            resolve(rows)
            reject('Error')
            connection.end();
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error during SELECT operation:', error);
        } finally {
            if (connection) {
                connection.end();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: If you do `connection.end()` in `finally` you don't need to do it in `try` as well.

Comment: You may simply have too many simultaneous clients, and you need to increase the maximum connections to handle them all.